# Responsive menu/small devices: close/collapse menu on clicking a menu item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, menu, menuitem

I want to change the behaviour of the Twitter Bootstrap Menu on small devices to close the expanded menu by either clicking on a menu item or clicking the menu button.

Currently (default) I can only collapse it by clicking the menu button in the top right corner, no matter if I'd clicked on a link/menu item or not. How would I do that? I couldn't figure it out from the TB documentation and searching the Internet didn't provide any answers.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the fix Skelly. It worked great on the "mobile" menu, but unfortunately it was causing a visual defect in "desktop" mode as it was targeting .nav-collapse, and this class is active in both modes.  So, I made a slight modification:

```
$('.nav li a').on('click',function(){
    $('.navbar-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
})
```

This modification will only invoke the 'hide' functionality when the menu is in "mobile" mode.

Note: This is only tested on Bootstrap 3.

Comment: I searched a lot for this answer thank you very much it was very helpfull.

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like..

```
$('.nav li a').on('click',function(){
    $('.nav-collapse').collapse('hide');
})
```

This will work for menu links that are referencing '#'. The menu should already be collapsing if your menu links navigate to another page on the site as this would cause a full page refresh.

Comment: Thank you, Skelly! I will try it. Problem is that I have a single page website, which uses anchors so the page won't be refreshed as the link will not navigate away from the current page.

Comment: That really does it! Thanks again!

Comment: This is a great answer. I didn't realize the default Bootstrap logic to collapse the menu does not work when using a single page app (like on an Angular.JS app.) I had to use $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide'); instead of "nav-collapse" but otherwise this works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by using HTML, add `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in"` to anchor

Example:

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in">Link</a></li>
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. Simple. Thanks.