# How to hide a bootstrap opened collapsed menu after clicking elsewhere on page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a bootstrap template and i need to hide/close an opened collapsed menu when someone clicks outside the menu. Here an image of the menu http://dev.flutechs.com/menu.png

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how the "collapsed menu" is being created.

If you use the standard Bootstrap dropdown menu, it will automatically close when elsewhere in the document is clicked...

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Menu
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice..</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you're using the `collapse` component, you can create a document `click` handler using jQuery..

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
})
```

### [Demo on Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/63158)

Comment: i am using this code for `nav-collapse` which have hash navigation and page links, hash is working but not page links... what do u suggest?

Comment: @SaurabhLP I think this other answer by Skelly might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/16901585/446681

Comment: do you really think it's a great idea to listen to every single click on the document and run the collapse script every time?

Comment: The question is about hiding opened collapsed menu when someone clicks OUTSIDE the menu. Your answer closes the collapsible even if clicked inside the menu

Comment: Anyway, this question is OBE. The questions' reference link is broken, and the bootstrap menu aleady does close when some clicks OUTSIDE the menu as stated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had 'collapse' applied to several div's on my page and once one of them had expanded its class changed to 'in' and not 'collapse' so using

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
    $('.in').collapse('hide'); //in instead of collapse
});
```

worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this script line and that's all.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

Comment: The question is about hiding opened collapsed menu when someone clicks OUTSIDE the menu. Your answer closes the collapsible even if clicked inside the menu

Comment: It is one of the solution of above problem. If toggle drop down is not properly initiate it won't work, only adding HTML does not guarantee it works. I don't know why you down vote it.