# Content is hidden by navigation bar. How to fix?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a problem with a website I am working at.

The site has a navigation bar which looks quite good on a bigger desktop screen.

But if I resize the screen it looks ugly and content is hidden behind the navigation bar.

How to fix this? Code is the following for the header:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar-fixed" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Dummy</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Werke</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Looks like Boostrap. You need to add the "Collapsable" class to the nav bar.

Comment: We need some code or tell us what templates you use.

Comment: I added the code for the navbar

Comment: code is incomplete, you have closing nav tag but no opening

Comment: I can not add it. Its in the editor but not shown in the code field (its cannot be seen by anybody but editor says its in the box. (i am confused) but thats not the problem, if I would missed that in the html code it wouldn't be shown

Comment: @user3821135 I have fixed your formatting so your code should all be showing now. You need to indent code with 4 spaces for it to show in a code block.

Comment: @user3821135 Does the dropdown in the menu work on the desktop view?

Comment: @AndrewPolland yeah its working. Why you removed the links? That are just placeholders which don't will be removed now or later.

Comment: @user3821135 Ok. Maybe my answer isn't relevant then. I didn't remove any links. The only bit I edited was the formatting of your code so that it would all show. The only other thing I've seen done is someone else changed your links to embedded images.

Comment: @AndrewPolland Doesn't solve my problem. The navigation bar still is shown over the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've found your issue. You need to wrap the menu in another `<div>` with the id which you have specified in your `data-target` attribute on the toggle button. And also give it the classes `collapse navbar-collapse`. So you will have the following for your menu section:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Werke</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I think just adding that div in should fix it. Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ca7B9/1/

Comment: Not working that way :( if I resize the website to a small view it reaches a maximum size and after that it can't be resized anymore. http://i.imgur.com/plPqHFl.png

Comment: @user3821135 I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. Your image link shows what I would expect at the size the browser is at.

Comment: wait that was a bug by my browser, I'll check it again.

Comment: @user3821135 Did you mean that the header isn't fluid width? That can be done by changing the <div> with class "container" to have class "container-fluid" instead.

Comment: Thankyou, but can you tell me how to add a feature that when i click on the menu button (on a mobile device) and click somewhere else the menu automatically hides? So i have to click once on the menu button to open the menu and to hide it I have to click on menu again. But I would like to click on a empty space and that the menu hides after that.

http://i.imgur.com/DrbZhUO.png

Comment: @user3821135 This might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919402/how-to-hide-a-bootstrap-opened-collapsed-menu-after-clicking-elsewhere-on-page Otherwise, as that's quite a different question from your original, I recommend creating a new question for it. You'll probably get some better answers that way, just make sure you include the relevant code with it.